# Jersey Viewable with Json

Tags: java, json, backbone.js, jersey

The JAX-RS implementation Jersey supports MVC style web applications through the Viewable class, which is a container for a template name and a model object. It is used like this:

```
@GET
@Template
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public Viewable get() {
    JsonObject response = null;
    try{
        response = service.getDetails(id);
        }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        log.error("failed to get details", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    return new Viewable("/test", response);
}
```

this is right way to send the json from Viewable? Is there a way to set a json object explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things: I don't have any experience using `Viewable` in particular, but I am familiar with JAX-RS and can probably throw a couple of pointers your way.

### Exception Handlers

JAX-RS defines a feature for mapping exceptions to responses. This functionality is nice for removing those exception blocks from your resource code. Check out the [Jersey docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665) on this topic for a tutorial on how to register these. A quick summary is: 1) implement [`ExceptionMapper`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) and 2) register the class as a Provider.

For starters, I recommend creating a simple suite that maps to common [HTTP codes](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#http-status). For example:

- `NotFoundException` - returns a 404 response and is used when a single entity is requested but not found.
- `InvalidInputException` - returns a 422 response and is used when a request does not pass validation (like trying to save an phone number in an email field).
- `BadRequestException` - usually the framework will handle these situations for you, but if not, a Bad Request is one that is not formatted properly. So if a required header is missing, or if a client tries to save a collection when only a single entity is allowed.
- `Exception`* - There is a star here because an unexpected exception is usually due to a server error, so 500 is an appropriate default response. A reason you *may* want to create a global uncaught exception handler is to prevent the stacktrace from being returned in the response body. That can be bad for security reasons.

### View and Model

You should not need the `@Template` annotation if you are using the `Viewable` object. Also, `Viewable` is expecting a template as the first argument and a model (map) as the second argument. The model should have keys that match variables in your JSP. Right now your method will look for a file called `test.jsp` in the root of whatever your template config is set to in web.xml. If you take all of that into consideration, your method could look something like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Viewable getMobileReport() {
    return new Viewable("/test", service.getMobileReport(id));
}
```

Comment: @mounish: You mean your object isn't being translated to JSON? There are libraries to do that for you so that you don't have to manually do it.

Comment: in my service response is coming as json object like above, but in client side i haven't find this in my backbone model. In my browser console jsp is coming as response.

Comment: I made some updates but it sounds like your issue is client side, not server side.